# Need some help printing strings in ASM program

Tags: string, assembly, character

here is the code:

```
 .model tiny

; assemble me this way
; ml /AT /c /Zm /coff /omf <file name>

; link me this way
; link2 /TINY <obj name>

COMSEG SEGMENT
org 7C00h

.code
start:
    MyStr BYTE "HelloWorld", '$'

    cld     ; Clear Direction Flag
    mov si, offset MyStr
whileloop: 
    lodsb                   ;; While Hello[Si] != '$' 
    cmp al, '$'
    jne doproc
    jmp endwhileloop
    doproc: 
        mov ah, 0ah           ;;     Video operation in Ah to write
                             ;;           character in Al to screen.
        mov bh, 0            ;;     Alpha page 0
        mov cx, 1
        int 10h      
        jmp whileloop
endwhileloop:
    jmp $                   

    db 510-($-start) dup (0)   ;Loads of zeroes
    dw 0AA55h  

end start
COMSEG ENDS
```

This code is only printing garbage to the cmd prompt. MASM, windows XP, running under 16 bit virtual machine. If someone could help me properly print out characters to the screen that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I am a bit rusty at this - but, although you are programing in the "tiny" model, you are not ensuring that DS (the Data Segmetn register) points to the memory segment where your DATA actually is.

If it is that, forcing DS = CS prior to enter your loop should make the code above work - 
just do:

```
push CS
pop DS
```

before the "whileloop:" line.

I don't recall the INT 10h call to check if they are ok, I am assuming you've set tjhe correct parameters there). Other than that you might have a problem with the specific syntax of MASM and I  can't  help with that.

Answer (score 0):

My assembly is a bit rusty, but you can use a DOS system call to print the string:

```
mov dx, offset MyStr
mov ah,9
int 21h
```

If you really want to use the BIOS routines, I think you need to load the `ah` register with 0eh, not 0ah.

Comment: So I tried to load the ah register with 0eh to use the BIOS routine and it still prints garbage. Are there any reasons not to use the DOS system call? I'm writing a bootloader so would using the DOS system calls cause any problems?

Comment: I think jsbueno is right, you haven't initialized the DS register.  Try jsbueno's suggestion of push cs, pop ds before the cld instruction.

Comment: Also you won't be able to call DOS from a bootloader, so the BIOS routine is the way to go.

Comment: AHa! You haven't said you were working with bare bootloader code! So, the program exectuion will start where you are putting DATA - the way your code is. The "MyStr" label will be placed at address 7c00 - and if this address is correct (I don't recall) it is where your bytes are copyed in memmory , and the excution then proceeds to that place: 0000:7c00 (even on 64 bit machines, so much for a 16 bit legacy) . Move the MySTr label and its data to the end of your listing. If that is not the error, at least you will prevent crashing from that.